# "Access denied" when trying to read logged in user profile from Microsoft Graph

Tags: java, spring-boot, microsoft-graph-api

I am integrating a spring-boot application through oauth2 with office365. This flow is implemented and functional: upon reaching my application, the user is redirected to the microsoft login page and returns logged in to my application. From the authentication details, I am able to retrieve user information such as the name and the email adress.

I would also like to retrieve the user's photo however, but I keep getting an "Insufficient Privileges to complete the operation". On the Azure portal, I have configured the User.Read privilege for the Microsoft Graph APIs as seen below. This should normally suffice to retrieve the picture of the user I think.

[image]

In my spring boot application, I attempt to retrieve the information as follows (the code isn't too great, I'm trying a simple proof of concept here):

```
@GetMapping("currentUser")
 public UserTo getCurrentUserInformation() throws IOException {
   Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
   UserTo user = new UserTo();
   Object details = auth.getDetails();
   if (details instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) {
    OAuth2AuthenticationDetails det = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) details;
    String tokenValue = det.getTokenValue();
    URL url = new URL("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/<tenantid>/me");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenValue);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    String response = getResponseStringFromConn(conn);
    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    if(responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { throw new IOException(response); }
   }
   user.setName(auth.getName());
   user.setPicData(response);
   return user;
}
```

1. I get an *Authorization_RequestDenied* with message *Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.* I have the exact same response if I leave out the tenantid part from the graphurl.
2. If I ask the picture instead of the full profile (i.e. use following URI "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value") then I get *ErrorAccessDenied* with message *Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.*

Those seem to be different errors, but I would assume both work (both require the User.read) privilege?

Any suggestions on why my calls fail?

Thanks

EDIT:

The first error (getting the entire profile) is:

```
{  "error": {    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",    "innerError": {      "date": "2020-08-07T16:38:23",      "request-id": "2dba6b3a-f5f7-4742-a7eb-a8a498c1a941"    }  }}.
```

The second error (getting the value of the picture) is:

```
{  "error": {    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",    "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",    "innerError": {      "date": "2020-08-07T16:40:10",      "request-id": "b28794e7-26e6-4c4e-8560-ba514b933171"    }  }}.
```

(I'm in Central Europe)

Comment: please share the correlation id and timestamp of your error message

Comment: May i  known why are using tenantid in graph api

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity I have added the full timestamp and requestid of the errors. I have no specific reason to use the tenantid, it was mainly trial and error. I assumed it was necessary as the privileges were specific to our company accounts, and should not apply to personal microsoft accounts.

Comment: Can you please confirm do you have a sufficient role?

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity I think so, I have configured the User.Read permission for this application. I have updated the image in the question to show the english version. Is there an additional permission I need to grant?

Comment: Have you given the scopes in your code? Did you validate the token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/) for the user. read scope. example:"scp": "openid User.Read profile email",

Comment: I have just got it to work... but I don't know why. It works if I give the permission "Admin Consent". However, that shouldn't be needed for the User.Read permission?

Comment: You mean to say grant admin consent right?